# Delimiting quick-open path with fullstops in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm making the move to ST3, and I'm having some trouble. I'd like to be able to delimit the quick-open filepath (⌘ + T) with periods instead of slashes or spaces. However, I can't find the setting to do that.

For example:

```
component.biz_site_promotions.presentation
```

should be able to open the file that

```
component biz_site_promotions presentation
```

would.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in Sublime that changes the way this works; the search term is always used to directly match the text in the list items (except for space characters).

Note however that the `Goto Anything` panel uses fuzzy matching on the text that you're entering, so in many cases trying to enter an entire file name is more time consuming anyway.

As an example, to find the file you're mentioning, you could try entering the text `cbspp`, which in this case is the first letters of all of the parts of the file name in question.

As you add to the search term, the file list immediately filters down to text that matches what you entered; first only filenames that contain a `C`, then only filenames that contain a `C` that is followed somewhere after by a `B`, and so on.

Depending on the complexity and number of files that you have in your project, you may need to add in a few extra characters to dial in better (e.g. `comb_s_pp`). Usually this search method will either end you up at the exact file you want, or filter the list so much that the file that you want will be easier to find and select.

Additionally, when you select an item and there was more than one possible match, Sublime remembers which item you selected for that particular search term and brings it to the top of the search results next time you do it, under the assumption that you want the same thing again.

As you use Sublime more (and with different projects) you will quickly get a handle on what partial search terms work the best for you.

In addition to finding files, you can do other things with that panel as well, such as jumping to a specific line and/or column or searching inside the file for a search term and jumping directly to it. This applies not only to the current file but also the one that you're about to open.

For more complete details, there is a page in the [Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html) that covers [File Navigation with Goto Anything](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html#goto-anything)

---

As an extra aside, starting with Sublime Text build 3154, the fuzzy searching algorithm handles spaces differently than previous builds. 
Historically, spaces in the search term are essentially ignored and the entire input is treated as one search term to be matched character by character.

Starting in build 3154, spaces are handled by splitting up a single search term into multiple search terms, which are applied one after the other.

This allows multiple search terms to hit out of order. For example, `index doc` in build 3154 will find `doc/index.html`, but it won't find it in previous versions because the terms aren't in the right order.

As such, assuming you're not currently using such a build (as of right now it's a development build, so only licensed users have access to it), moving forward if you continue to search the way you're searching in your question, you might start getting more results than you expected.